# Renombrar los valores de una columna previo haber eliminado las que no interesan - PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un fichero csv donde por un error se me duplicaron dos filas. Y querría eliminarlas y renombrar la columna code, pues se compone de un prefijo y del valor de la fila.

Hago lo siguiente (los valores repetidos son los que en code aparece "Feat_022" y "Feat_0044"):

```
from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame

df = read_csv('results.csv')
print(len(df))

df = df.drop(df[df['Code'] == 'Feat_0022'].index)
df = df.drop(df[df['Code'] == 'Feat_0044'].index)

print(len(df))

for s in range(len(df)):
  i = s+1
  if i < 10:
    code = 'ImgANN_000'+str(i)
  elif 10 <= i < 100:
    code = 'ImgANN_00'+str(i)
  elif 100 <= i < 1000:
    code = 'ImgANN_0'+str(i)
  else:
    code ='ImgANN_'+str(i)
  
  df.loc[s, "Code"] = code

df.to_csv('final.csv', index=None, header=True)
```

Al imprimir los dos `prints` la cosa parece que funciona, pues pasa de 213 valores a 211. Por lo tanto lo que hago luego es un bucle que recorre el dataframe y va sustituyendo el valor. **El problema** viene cuando abro el fichero resultante "final.csv", pues si se han eliminado las dos filas deseadas, ha pasado de poner "Feat_xxx" (este era otro error) a poner "ImgANN_", pero tanto en el 22, como el 44, se los salta.

Seguro es simple el error, que no debo guardar algo, pero por mucho que lo miro no termino de entender que sucede.

A continuación muestro una imagen del dataframe original donde se ve un poco la estructura y la línea con "Feat_022".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ahora el resultado final, donde la cuenta no se ha hecho bien pues pasa de 21 a 23 (la fecha esta desplazada sin querer) y de 43 a 45.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias, un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independientemente de si se puede optimizar o no el código, el problema que tienes parece ser que cuando haces `df.loc[s, "Code"] = code` estás asignando los valores a un índice en el que han desaparecido el 22 y el 44.

Tras borrar las líneas debes resetear el índice, pues quedarán los huecos. Usa:

`df.reset_index(drop=True)`

El parámetro `drop=True` se usa para que no te añada una columna nueva con el índice y simplemente lo borre.

**EDITO:**

Este código resuelve el problema y además queda más limpio, más *pythónico* :)

```
from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame

df = read_csv('results.csv')
df = df.drop(df[df['Code'] == 'Feat_0022'].index)
df = df.drop(df[df['Code'] == 'Feat_0044'].index)
df.reset_index(drop=True)
df["Code"] = df.apply(lambda row: f"ImgANN_{row.name:04d}", axis=1)
df.to_csv('final.csv', index=None, header=True)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, como se podría optimizar? Estoy seguro no hace falta el `for` pero no se como hacerlo. Un saludo!

Comment: Edito la respuesta para añadir un ejemplo con la misma funcionalidad pero sin usar el `for`.